# How to make text wrap to next line in Vuetify.js

Tags: html, vuetify.js

I am trying to add a large block of text to an HTML element, but the text all remains a single line, going off the right side of the screen, rather than wrapping to multiple lines. Not sure if this is a regular HTML/CSS problem or a Vuetify problem.

```html
<v-flex>
    <v-card>
        <v-container>
            <p>
                 {{ stringToDisplay }}
            </p>
        <v-container>
    </v-card>
</v-flex>
```

Comment: Is the text composed of a normal length words separated by spaces? Or is it just a never ending string of characters with no spaces like this: `fajlsajasjkgsaklgsjalgaj...` ?

Comment: along with max-width css property you can use overflow-wrap: break-word as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `text-wrap` / `text-no-wrap` class.
Something like below :

```
<v-flex>
    <v-card>
        <v-container>
            <p class="text-wrap">
                 {{ stringToDisplay }}
            </p>
        <v-container>
    </v-card>
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution for my scenario was adding `word-break: break-word;` to my class. The built in classnames did not do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can use the `text-truncate` class.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#wrapping-and-overflow